# How to configure anaconda kickstart EFI boot

Tags: fedora, pxe, kickstart, installer-anaconda

Im trying to install my host via anaconda kickstart and im unable to get efi boot working. This is my kickstart file (Disk partitioning part):

```
zerombr
bootloader --location=mbr --append="net.ifnames=0 biosdevname=0"
clearpart --all --initlabel

# Partitions before LVM
part /boot/efi --fstype="efi" --size=600 --fsoptions="umask=0077,shortname=winnt"
part /boot --fstype="ext4" --size=1024

part pv.e11c072ace5b --grow --size=1000 --ondrive=sda

# LVM Config
volgroup base --pesize=32768 pv.e11c072ace5b
logvol / --fstype=ext4 --name=lv_root --vgname=base --size=32768
logvol swap --fstype swap --name=lv_swap --vgname=base --size=8192
logvol /space --fstype=ext4 --name=lv_space --vgname=base --size=50000 --grow
```

This results in the following partition table (Checked via live boot stick):

```
sda                  8:0      0 238,5G  0 disk 
-> sda1               8:1     0  1024M  0 part /boot
-> sda2               8:2     0 237,3G  0 part 
---> base-lv_root     253:0   0    32G  0 lvm  /
---> base-lv_swap     253:1   0     8G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
---> base-lv_space    253:2   0 197,3G  0 lvm  /space
-> sda3               8:3     0   600M  0 part /boot/efi
```

According to the efi documentation `sda3` should be fine, as long as it holds the correct efi files. But if i mount `/dev/sda3` i can see, that this partition is completely empty. What did i do wrong in my anaconda file?

***Note: Im trying do install fedora33 here. I dont know if that makes any difference to other linux distributions***

Comment: FYI specifying MBR for EFI does not seem to be correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out now. The problem was caused by a broken vmlinuz.